# Aplicar hpfilter a una base de datos de panel con NAs

Tags: r, r-dplyr

Tengo una base de datos de panel (id + año) y estoy tratando de aplicar el filtro hp a una de las variables de mi base de datos (esta variable tiene NAs) y luego agregar las series filtradas a mi base de datos. Necesito mantener los valores faltantes en el resultado final (las variables con la tendencia y el ciclo). Mi problema es que el código que estoy utilizando no tiene en cuenta que tengo una base de datos de panel. Asume que todos los valores de una variable corresponden a la misma unidad de análisis. En consecuencia, el resultado final que obtengo es erróneo.

En los próximos renglones muestro un ejemplo reproducible, el código que estoy utilizando y cómo se que dicho código está mal.

El ejemplo reproducible:

```
df1  <- read.table(text="pais   año   X1  X2    W
                   A         1990   10  20    40
                   A         1991   12  15    NA
                   A         1992   14  17    41
                   A         1993   17  NA    44
                   B         1990   20  NA    45
                   B         1991   NA  13    61
                   B         1992   12  12    67
                   B         1993   14  10    68
                   C         1990   10  20    70
                   C         1991   11  14    50
                   C         1992   12  15    NA
                   C         1993   14  16    NA
                   D         1990   20  17    80
                   D         1991   16  20    91
                   D         1992   15  21    70 
                   D         1993   14  22    69
                   ", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

El código que estoy utilizando:

```
library(mFilter)
library(plm)
library(dplyr)
df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(pais) %>% 
  filter(!is.na(X1)) %>% 
  pdata.frame(., index = c("pais","año")) %>% 
  mutate(X1_tendencia = mFilter::hpfilter(X1, type = "lambda", freq = 6.25)$trend)
df3 <- merge(df1,df2, by = colnames(df1),all.x = T)
```

Noten que si utilizo este código los valores de X1_tendencia para A-1990, A-1991, A-1992, A-1993 son 11.16954, 12.76886, 14.18105 y 15.09597 respectivamente.

Finalmente, se que este código está mal porque si le aplico hpfilter a X1 en una base de datos que tiene las observaciones del país A solamente, los valores de la tendencia para X1 para A-1990, A-1991, A-1992, A-1993 son 9.818, 12.084, 14.379 y 16.719 respectivamente. Esto es, son diferentes de los que obtengo si ejecuto el código que mencioné más arriba para la base de datos de panel completa.

A continuación pego el código que aplica hpfilter a X1 en una base de datos que tiene las observaciones del país A solamente:

```
dfa<-subset.data.frame(x = df1,`pais`=="A")
dfahp <- hpfilter(dfa$X1,type = "lambda",freq = 6.25)
dfahp
```

Les estaría muy agradecido si me pueden ayudar. Muchísimas gracias.